# Semi-Complex SQL into Django ORM, uses SELECT in WHERE, COUNT and DISTINCT

Tags: sql, django, orm

Here is some SQL I want to turn into Django ORM code. If I must use raw() or extra() then that's ok.

I have a SQL fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/14118/8

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE box (
  num int,
  group1 char(8),
  group2 char(8)
);

INSERT INTO box (num, group1, group2) VALUES 
  (4,  'group_a','group_ab'),
  (8,  'group_a', 'group_ab'),
  (12, 'group_a', 'group_ab'),
  (4,  'group_b', 'group_ab'),
  (8,  'group_c', 'group_cd'),
  (16, 'group_a', 'group_ab'),
  (16, 'group_b', 'group_ab');
```

First case, I only want results for which the number of results with the matching group1 value exceeds a number (here it's '2').

```
SELECT *
FROM box
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM box as b
   WHERE group1 = box.group1
) > 2;
```

Output:

```
| num |   group1 |   group2 |
|-----|----------|----------|
|   4 | group_a  | group_ab |
|   8 | group_a  | group_ab |
|  12 | group_a  | group_ab |
|  16 | group_a  | group_ab |
```

Second case, I only want results for which the number of results with the matching group2 value exceeds a number (here it's '4'). I also only want results for which there are exactly two rows sharing the same 'num' value. Finally, I want the results to be distinct for the 'num' column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT on (num) *
FROM box
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM box as b
   WHERE group2 = box.group2
   ) > 4
AND (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM box as b
   WHERE group2 = box.group2
   AND num = box.num
   ) = 2
```

Output:

```
| num |   group1 |   group2 |
|-----|----------|----------|
|   4 | group_a  | group_ab |
|  16 | group_a  | group_ab |
```

Comment: It is kind of hard to understand what you expect the return to be. Can you provide the result set you would expect for each query?

Comment: I've added the output. Also take a look at the sql fiddle.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I though your queries were still not returning what you want but it looks like they are. If so, those are very advanced queries and .raw() would be best. If you need model objects you can select only id/pk and then run a standard Box.objects.filter(pk__in=list_of_ids).all()

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming that raw() is necessary. Thanks for the filter by pk technique also, I will use that.